# How do I set table prefix in Yii

Tags: php, yii

In a project I am working on I need to set a table prefix for the project which I can change later. Browsing through the docs I came across this :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#tablePrefix-detail

But it is not explained where I implement this. I mean should I put it in protected/config/main.php or edit the core files ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You put it in the config file, along with other db configuration, like this:

```
'db'=>array(
  'connectionString' => 'xxxxx',
  'username' => 'xxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
```

All public properties of any component can be set in the config file this way.

Answer (score -3):

```
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => '###',
        'password' => '###',
        'charset' => '###',
        'tablePrefix' => 'r_',
    ),
```

Comment: welcome to SO. As you might have seen, this qestion was already answered. As ou provided a, slightly different answer, you should also explain a little bit more about your method, as in where you put this code and etc. Also you should explain why is your answer better than the previous one